# Local image doesn't work on markdown with <img

Tags: html, markdown, documentation

I'm trying to use markdown to generate a documentation. When i use `<img alt="IMAGE ALT TEXT HERE" width="240" height="180" border="10" src='http://img.youtube.com/vi/YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID_HERE/0.jpg'/>` it's working and it shows the image but when i put `<img alt="IMAGE ALT TEXT HERE" width="240" height="180" border="10" src='test.jpg'/>` doesn't work although the image test.jpg is on the same folder with the mardown file.

I want to use <img because i want to align my image to the center !

Answer (score 0):

The first one

```
<img alt="IMAGE ALT TEXT HERE" width="240" height="180" border="10" src='http://img.youtube.com/vi/YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID_HERE/0.jpg' />
```

works because the image source is from img.youtube.com

---

The second one

```
<img alt="IMAGE ALT TEXT HERE" width="240" height="180" border="10" src='test.jpg'/>
```

has a local stored image source from your computer. As far as I know it is not only enough to enter the name of the picture but you must also write in your path.

Try something like this (example)

```
src="C:\Users\YourPCName\Documents\YourSaveFolder\test.jpg
```

Please note that you have to change the path accordingly when uploading to a webspace/server in general.

Let me know if it works!

Cheers,
Kevin

Comment: Sorry, i'm under Ubuntu 16.04. I tried to put the whole path of the image (absolute path from /home/....) but it doesn't work. I think <img don't work in markdown with local file.